# Proving infinite set

Tags: elementary-set-theory

How would one go about solving this problem.

Let A be a set. Prove that:

1. (**ZF**) If there $\exists B(B \subseteq A \land B \neq A \land |B| = |A|) \Rightarrow$ A is infinite
2. (**ZFC**) If A is infinite $\Rightarrow \exists B(B \subseteq A \land B \neq A \land |B| = |A|)$

Honestly I am clueless due to the fact that a set(B) can be a subset to another set(A) and have the same cardinality like it. Maybe I am not used to the idea of infinite sets. Thats what is mainly throwing me off. I would appreciate if anyone could explain and help me prove.

Comment: For number two you should prove $B$ can be $A- \{ a_0\} $

Comment: For 1) have a look at [Dedekind infinite set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dedekind-infinite_set).

Comment: The ability to have a strict subset of the same cardinality is characteristic of infinite sets.  For a simple example consider the natural numbers with zero and the natural numbers without zero.  The second is a strict subset of the first but $n \rightarrow n + 1$ is a bijection between them hence they have the same cardinality.

Comment: Some other well-known examples of subsets of infinite sets that are still the same size: $$|\{\text{even naturals}\}| = |\{\text{odd naturals}\}| =  |\{\text{primes}\}| = |\Bbb N|\\|\Bbb N| = |\Bbb Z\| = |\Bbb Q| = |\{\text{algebraic}\}| \\|\{\text{irrationals}\}| =  |\{\text{trancendentals}\}| = |[0,1]| = |\Bbb R| = |\Bbb C|$$ More generally, *any* non-empty set of integers that does not have a largest element will be the same size as $\Bbb N$.

Comment: You may find it useful to investigate [the Hilbert Hotel](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Uj3_KqkI9Zo).

Comment: Thank you for the pointers, I found them helpful. I still having trouble proving the above, I will do further reading.